# Add multiple users in Subversion

Tags: apache, .htpasswd

I am following the method described in http://www.maketecheasier.com/setting-up-subversion-version-control-in-ubuntu for creating a subversion repo.It works fine.
But when I try to  create a second user using

```
sudo htpasswd -cm /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd yourusername
```

, the current user gets deleted and it gets replaced by the new user. How can I create additional users?
/etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd file contains only the latest user credentials I added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution from http://www.wandisco.com/svnforum/threads/33361-creating-a-new-svn-user-with-password?s=ea3c8ce175b09de948e8aafe7d4f8ab6&p=124540&viewfull=1#post124540.

For adding another user

```
#sudo htpasswd -m /etc/.svn-auth-file <username>
```

should be used instead of

```
#sudo htpasswd -cm /etc/.svn-auth-file <username>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add one user  :

```
sudo htpasswd -cs /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd username
```

to add many users

```
sudo htpasswd -s /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd userX
```